# jQuery text-field live-search with comma-separated keywords

Tags: jquery, search, filter, textinput, keyword-search

I am trying to create a live-search with jQuery and comma-separated keywords.
If I only take the complete string from text-field as keyword, the search works like a charm.

Code (working for single keyword):

```
jQuery("#artikelfilter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = jQuery(this).val(), count = 0;

    // Loop through the comment list
    jQuery("#liste-alles li").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            jQuery(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
        } else {
            jQuery(this).show();
            count++;
        }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    jQuery("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
});
```

What I am trying to do now, is to filter with multiple keywords. I thought about splitting the string into an array and loop through the keywords. The problem is, that I get loads of jQuery events, so the browser can not handle it anymore.

Is there any smart way to make this work?

The code for multiple keywords (not working):

```
jQuery("#artikelfilter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var string_filter = jQuery(this).val();
    var array_filter = string_filter.split(',');

    // Loop through the comment list
    jQuery("#liste-alles li").each(function(){

        jQuery.each( array_filter, function( intValue, currentFilter ) {
            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                jQuery(this).fadeOut();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                jQuery(this).show();
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery.each( array_filter, function( intValue, currentFilter ) {
    jQuery("#liste-alles li:contains("+currentFilter +")").show();
    jQuery("#liste-alles li:not(:contains("+currentFilter +"))").fadeOut();

});
```

or this

```
var regex = new RegExp(filter, "i"));

jQuery.each( array_filter, function( intValue, currentFilter ) {

   jQuery("#liste-alles li").filter(function () {return regex.test($(this).text()); }).show();
   jQuery("#liste-alles li").filter(function () {return !regex.test($(this).text()); }).fadeOut();

});
```

Comment: This one works perfect! Thank you very much. Now it is flickering a little bit when I am typing. Do you know how I can make the keyup function run with a delay? This would make the whole thing a little bit smoother... :)

Comment: Welcome :) Let me think and I will update the answer